# Clean a column name in R

Tags: r

I have several headers in my data frame that are as follow

Page.Visits...ba_rm..Total.Conversions
Page.Visits...aaa.d.s..Total.Conversions

I want to get rid of all what's around the middle part **aaa.d.s**,
so the new column name will be **aaa_d_s** only. the rule here is to keep anything that appears between ...middle.. (3 dots and 2 dots)

How do I do I clean it automatically for all columns in my data frame?

Comment: Is it always the text inbetween the `: ... :` that you want to extract?

Comment: Hi, can you give us a sample of your data?  Try `dput(mydata)`.

Comment: Posting a dataset would really help...

Comment: Page Visits : adv_r: Total Conversions Page Visits : abs_lg: Total Conversions Page Visits : addesk: Total Conversions
2 7 2
6 3 1
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0

Comment: I am not sure how to post a datates but above is an example of the other columns name, all numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sub` with an appropriate regular expression:

```
sub(".*: ([a-z_]+) :.*","\\1","Page Visits : aaa_d_s : Total Conversions")
[1] "aaa_d_s"
```

Comment: would this work if the middle part was something like `col1`?

Comment: @docendodiscimus You would need to put something in the square brackets part to match the structure of what was in the middle part, eg `[a-z0-9_]`

Comment: Or, more generally (and more riskily) `".+"`.

Comment: I tried this names(raw) <-sub(".*: ([a-z_]+) :.*","\\1",names(raw))

Comment: but nothing changed in the columns name

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
require(dplyr)
data(iris)

existingDF <- iris
existingDF <- existingDF %>% select("Page Visits : aaa_d_s : Total Conversions" = Sepal.Length)
head(existingDF)


updatedDF <- existingDF %>% setNames(tolower(sub(".*: ([a-z_]+) :.*","\\1","Page Visits : aaa_d_s : Total Conversions")))
head(updatedDF)
```

output:

```
> require(dplyr)
> data(iris)
> existingDF <- iris
> existingDF <- existingDF %>% select("Page Visits : aaa_d_s : Total Conversions" = Sepal.Length)

> head(existingDF)
  Page Visits : aaa_d_s : Total Conversions
1                                       5.1
2                                       4.9
3                                       4.7
4                                       4.6
5                                       5.0
6                                       5.4

> updatedDF <- existingDF %>% setNames(tolower(sub(".*: ([a-z_]+) :.*","\\1","Page Visits : aaa_d_s : Total Conversions")))

> head(updatedDF)
  aaa_d_s
1     5.1
2     4.9
3     4.7
4     4.6
5     5.0
6     5.4
```

My recommendation is that you take a look at how regular expressions work in R. The base documentation is pretty good.

- https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html

for more detail

- https://bioinfomagician.wordpress.com/2013/10/27/regular-expression-tutorial-1-special-characters/
- https://bioinfomagician.wordpress.com/2013/11/03/regular-expression-tutorial-2-commands-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, "(?<=:\\s)[^ ]+")
#[1] "aaa_d_s"
```

To update the column name, we can just use

```
names(existingDF) <- str_extract(names(existingDF), "(?<=:\\s)[^ ]+")
names(existingDF)
#[1] "aaa_d_s"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "Page Visits : aaa_d_s : Total Conversions"
```

Comment: All the columns name seems to disappear when I run the above,  I am not sure why it is happening.

Comment: Columns name are now: NA

Comment: @user4797853  Based on the example you showed and based on Technophobe01's example, it isworking

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution with gsub:

I remove the prefix

```
names(raw) <- gsub("\\Page.Visits...", "", names(raw))
```

and removing the end part

```
names(raw) <- gsub("\\..Total.Conversions", "", names(raw))
```